# Equivalent of .Net file routines (StreamReader, Filestream, etc) in MinGW

Tags: .net, mingw

I'm slowly trying to move to all open source tools, but it seems I've become quite spoiled at using the .net framework.

I understand Mono is an open source alternative to .Net, but I'm using MinGW with CodeBlocks.. Not sure if it's possible to use Mono within CodeBlocks, so I'm wondering if there's another MingW friendly library that can work like StreamReader?   Like a modern day version of FILE *fopen.

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,         FileShare.ReadWrite)))
{
   string line;
   while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
        // Do work here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. .NET become [open source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) - you can continue using them even if you opensource zealot
2. You still may use your .NET skills with Mono, with [Xamarin Studio](http://xamarin.com/studio) as IDE
3. MinGW is not a complete platform like .NET, it is just a port of GNU Compilers Collection to Windows. If your question is "what language from GCC provide stream-oriented file API?", then [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) is an answer.
4. If fact, these StreamReader/TextReader APIs in C# is a direct copy from [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), there is a Java compiler in GCC/MinGW, but full-featured [Oracle Java platform](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) is opensource too.